# Angular 4 Kendo UI Grid first row selected by default when grid loads

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get the first row of the angular kendo grid selected by default when the grid loads. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 10):

You have to setup the `[kendoGridSelectBy]` and `[selectedKeys]` properties to do this.

**Pay attention** - the `[selectedKeys]` property not works without `[kendoGridSelectBy]` and it throw an error `Can't bind to 'selectedKeys' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'`.

Read https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/#toc-persisting-the-selection for more information.

Comment: thank you, i was missing this kendoGridSelectBy property. You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selection persisting function of the grid.

In your ts code add something like that:

```
private mySelection: number[] = [0];
```

In the html add that:

```
<kendo-grid [selectedKeys]="mySelection"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Gettting this error.Can't bind to 'selectedKeys' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'.

Comment: Not sure but you might have to update to the latest version of Kendo Grid.